# Determine actual max local memory

Tags: opencl

When generating a kernel with local memory of compile-time defined size like

```
__local float2 block[%d];
```

How can I determine the size that will actually be available when running the kernel?

It's not CL_DEVICE_LOCAL_MEM_SIZE, when I use this I get an error message telling me the maximum allowable amount, which is always less than the reported value (also: not a power of 2, does it substract the registers used by the kernel?).

Currently I'm simply using half the reported size...

Answer (score 0):

I *cannot* confirm this. To verify this I created a little [test program](https://github.com/matze/oclkit/blob/master/maxlocal.c) that determines the maximum local memory per device and creates a kernel that allocates that amount. The program executes successfully unless I increase the amount by at least one byte.

Maybe your problem lies in `float2`. That takes eight bytes and if you set the `block` array length to the maximum local memory size, it won't work.